# Pandoc tex to html: how to handle custom environments?

Tags: pandoc

I am trying to convert a large body of tex code into html using Pandoc. I have multiple custom-defined environments and commands in the LaTeX source that I would like to tag with classes in the resulting HTML.

How can I make sure that the following LaTeX code:

```
\begin{myspecialenvironment}
 hello
\end{myspecialenvironment}
```

is converted to the following HTML

```
<div class="myspecialenvironment">
 hello
</div>
```

and the following LaTeX

```
\myspecialcommand{hola}
```

converted to HTML as follows?

```
<span class="myspecialcommand">hola</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and looked in vain for relevant documentation, but then I noticed that Pandoc is already doing what you propose, at least for block environments. :-) I don't know about inline commands.